# Can I open the chromedriver.exe (FireFox / IE) using getResource? *Selenium-Java

Tags: java, eclipse, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

My problem is, I exported my project (eclipse Java) using Runnable Jar File and on my computer it's ok but in others computers the Runnable does not work.

The idea was put the chromedriver.exe on eclipse folder (like getResource res>images) and after that everyone will get the entire program.

Any idea how to do that? That's my code, the chromedrivers is static on my C:\ :

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver","C:\\SeleniumAssets\\chromedriver_win32\\chromedriver.exe");
    DesiredCapabilities capabilities=DesiredCapabilities.chrome();
    capabilities.setCapability("marionette", true);
    driver = new ChromeDriver();
    driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

    driver.get(Constant.URL);


    //signIn.ExecuteGerenteOperacional(driver,Constant.Username_GO,Constant.Password_GO);
    //signIn.ExecuteGerenteLoja(driver,Constant.Username_Gerente_Loja,Constant.Password_Gerente_Loja);
    //signIn.ExecuteVendedor(driver,Constant.Username_Vendedor,Constant.Password_Vendedor);
    ActionsDO();

}
```

Thanks :)

Edited:

```
    ClassLoader loader = ClassLoader.getSystemClassLoader();
    URL path = loader.getResource("\\res\\drivers\\chromedriver.exe");
    System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", path.getPath());
```

Does not work too.

Comment: Would it be possible to work with properties and a defined folder where the driver has to be put?

Comment: Yes, that's the idea, but when I do some like this System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver","/res/drivers/chromedriver.exe"); Eclipse show "The driver executable does not exist C:\res\drivers\chromedriver.exe"

Answer (score 0):

If you can place the driver in a 'standard' directory (like user home > driver) it would be an option to use the system property that works OS independent:

1) Place the driver in i.e. \driver\chromedriver.exe

2) In your code use:

```
String userHome = System.getProperty("user.home");
String pathToDriver = userHome + File.separator + "driver" + File.separator + "chromedriver.exe";
System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", pathToDriver);
```

HTH

Comment: Whats currentUsersHomeDir ? Is it a constant?

Comment: Corrected. Wrong variable name.

Answer (score 0):

You should use the `setBinary` of `ChromeOptions` with the relative path of the added chromedriver, code is from [here](https://www.selenium.dev/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/chrome/ChromeOptions.html):

```
ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
options.setBinary(new File("/path/to/chrome"));
ChromeDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(options);
```

Comment: I tried this but and the "webdriver.chrome.driver" ?

Comment: I'm sorry, what is your question?